# Build timeline from start and end dates

Tags: sql-server, date, subscription, timeline

I have a subscription table with a *user ID*, a *subscription start date* and a *subscription end date*. I also have a calendar table with a *datestamp* field, that is every single date starting from the first subscription date in my subscription table.

I am trying to write something that would give me a table with a date column and three numbers: number of total active (on that day), number of new subscribers, number of unsubscribers.

*(N.B. I tried to insert sample tables using the suggested GitHub Flavoured Markdown but it just all goes into one row.)*

Currently I am playing with a query that creates multiple joins between the two tables, one for each number:

```
select a.datestamp
,count(distinct case when b_sub.UserID is not null then b_sub.UserID end) as total_w_subscription
,count(distinct case when b_in.UserID is not null then b_in.UserID end) as total_subscribed
,count(distinct case when b_out.UserID is not null then b_out.UserID end) as total_unsubscribed

from Calendar as a

left join Subscription as b_sub -- all those with subscription on given date
on b_sub.sub_dt <= a.datestamp
and (b_sub.unsub_dt > a.datestamp or b_sub.unsub_dt is null)

left join Subscription as b_in -- all those that subscribed on given date
on b_in.sub_dt = a.datestamp

left join Subscription as b_out -- all those that unsubscribed on given date
on b_out.unsub_dt = a.datestamp

where a.datestamp > '2021-06-10'

group by a.datestamp
order by datestamp asc
;
```

I have indexed the date fields in both tables. If I only look at one day, it runs in 3 seconds. Two days already takes forever. The Sub table is over 2.6M records and ideally I'll need my timeline to begin sometime in 2012.

What would be the most time efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. I created some table variables and assumed a data structure that has each subscription include a start and end date.

```
--Create @dates table variable for calendar
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME = '2018-01-01'
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME = '2021-06-18'
DECLARE @dates TABLE
(
reportingdate DATETIME
)
WHILE @startDate <= @endDate
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @dates SELECT @startDate
    SET @startDate += 1
END

--Create @subscriptions table variable for subcriptions to join onto calendar
DECLARE @subscriptions TABLE
(
id INT
,startDate DATETIME
,endDate DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO @subscriptions
VALUES
(1,'2018-01-01 00:00:00.000','2019-10-07 00:00:00.000')
,(2,'2018-01-11 00:00:00.000','2019-12-21 00:00:00.000')
,(3,'2019-04-21 00:00:00.000','2020-03-19 00:00:00.000')
,(4,'2019-12-09 00:00:00.000','2020-05-14 00:00:00.000')
,(5,'2020-04-26 00:00:00.000','2020-07-06 00:00:00.000')
,(6,'2020-05-02 00:00:00.000',NULL)
,(7,'2020-08-31 00:00:00.000','2020-10-29 00:00:00.000')
,(8,'2020-12-13 00:00:00.000','2021-01-13 00:00:00.000')
,(9,'2021-02-12 00:00:00.000','2021-04-19 00:00:00.000')
,(10,'2021-06-10 00:00:00.000',NULL)
;
```

Then I join the subscription onto the calendar table.

```
--CTE to join subscription onto calendar and use ROW_NUMBER functions
WITH cte AS (
SELECT
    s.id AS SubID
    ,d.ReportingDate
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.id ORDER BY d.ReportingDate) AS asc_rn   --used to identify 1st
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.id ORDER BY d.ReportingDate DESC) AS desc_rn --used to identify last
    ,CASE WHEN s.endDate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ActiveSub
FROM @subscriptions s
LEFT JOIN @dates d ON
    d.reportingdate BETWEEN s.startDate AND ISNULL(s.endDate,'9999-12-31')
    )
```

I used ROW_NUMBER to identify the first and last date rows of the subscription, as well as checking if the subscription endDate is NULL (still active). I then query the CTE to count subscriptions grouped by day, as well as summing new and terminated subscriptions grouped by day.

```
--Query CTE using asc_rn, desc_rn, and ActiveSub to identify new subscribers and unsubscribers.
SELECT
    ReportingDate
    ,COUNT(*) AS TotalSubscribers
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN asc_rn = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NewSubscribers
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN desc_rn = 1 AND ActiveSub = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS UnSubscribers
FROM cte
GROUP BY ReportingDate
ORDER BY ReportingDate
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really neat! I've tried it with 100K records and it ran in just under 10 min, just running it with the full 2.6M. I also tried it without the table as variable (i.e. just running it on the tables as they are) and that never finished, so I'm guessing it's the temp table written into memory that makes it tick so fast, right?

Comment: Reading from memory always helps, and the calendar table variable is a cheap and re-producible process if you just need dates, but if you might eventually use other fields from the calendar table (fiscal year/quarter, etc...) you may want to analyze the execution plan using the tables to look for improvements via missing indexes. If I had to guess, the query will likely benefit from an index on the subscriptions table using start and stop dates including the ID.

Comment: I will do! I also changed it to run on an aggregate which cut the run time down from over 4 hours to 1.5, which is awesome! Thank you again.